# Two computers write same USB SSD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, filesystems

I am trying to understand if it is possible to have a single SSD with a single filesystem that can be read and written by multiple computers at the same time via USB 3.0.

I've been looking for information, but I don't know if the technology exists.

Answer (score 1):

Linux does come with a few filesystems which could be used for such situations – for example, OCFS2 and GFS2 support shared storage.

However, your hardware does not. While there are enterprise storage systems which allow multiple hosts to be directly attached to the same disks through SAS (SCSI), the same is not true for USB – your USB device is single-host only.

(There are also a few reasons that make me expect doing so with a cheap USB-connected HDD would actually end up being *slower* than accessing the HDD through SMB/NFS file-sharing from one computer to another.)

Answer (score 1):

As you say that the disk is USB, meaning inside a USB enclosure,
you may share it among the computers in the local network.

The disk will be connected to one of the computers, and that computer will share
it as a network share. It should be the computer that most uses the disk,
as locally referencing the disk will be much faster for it.

The other computers will access the share over the local network as
`\\computer\share-name`.